# XML Handling using X-path using Java/groovy script

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

I have a very deep/nested structure xml where I need to filter only those fields which will be declared in some store(parameter let's say). Or the other solution is , I need to make those field values as "X" which are not stored in the parameters. As the structure is very deep, I suppose the field should be declared in the parameter as x-path.
Please suggest some clues.

I am using the below code now but this is removing all the fields under different nodes as well. I want to remove this from a particular node. For example(as shown below) field 'action' is present in many nodes but I want to remove this from some specific nodes.

Or I want to set this field value as "X".

```
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(body)
def nodes = xml.'**'.findAll{ node -> node.name() == 'action' }
//nodes.each{it.text()}
def removeNode = { node ->
   def parent = node.parent()
   parent.remove(node)
}
 
nodes.each{removeNode(it)}
def final_body = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml);
```

My input data is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<query>
    <Emp>
        <id>34032</id>
        <ps>
            <action>INSERT</action>
            <id>34032</id>
            <PI>
                <action>INSERT</action>
                <gen>M</gen>
                <ms>S</ms>
                <PI_mex>
                    <action>INSERT</action>
                    <genericNumber1>0</genericNumber1>
                    <genericNumber2>0</genericNumber2>
                    <genericNumber3>0</genericNumber3>
                    <genericNumber4>0</genericNumber4>
                    <genericNumber5>0</genericNumber5>
                    <genericNumber6>0</genericNumber6>
                    <genericNumber7>0</genericNumber7>
                </PI_mex>
            </PI>
            <PI>
                <action>INSERT</action>
                <gen>M</gen>
                <ms>S</ms>
                <PI_mex>
                    <action>INSERT</action>
                    <genericNumber1>0</genericNumber1>
                    <genericNumber2>0</genericNumber2>
                    <genericNumber3>0</genericNumber3>
                    <genericNumber4>0</genericNumber4>
                    <genericNumber5>0</genericNumber5>
                    <genericNumber6>0</genericNumber6>
                    <genericNumber7>0</genericNumber7>
                </PI_mex>
            </PI>
            <ai>
                <action>INSERT</action>
                <city>SAN NICOALAS DE LOS GARZA</city>
                <country>MEX</country>
                <state>NLE</state>
                <zip_code>66420</zip_code>
            </ai>
            <ai>
                <action>INSERT</action>
                <city>SAN NICOALAS DE LOS GARZA</city>
                <country>MEX</country>
                <state>NLE</state>
                <zip_code>66420</zip_code>
            </ai>
            <ei>
                <action>INSERT</action>
                <id>26658</id>
                <user_id>00860884</user_id>
                <ji>
                    <action>INSERT</action>
                    <c_string10>5</c_string10>
                    <c_string11>P</c_string11>
                    <c_string12>MX_F_1E</c_string12>
                    </ji>
                <ji>
                    <action>INSERT</action>
                    <c_string10>5</c_string10>
                    <c_string11>P</c_string11>
                    <c_string12>MX_F_1E</c_string12>
                    <c_string13>1310</c_string13>
                    <c_string16>90000269</c_string16>
                    <c_string17>Y</c_string17>
                    <c_string18>BCC</c_string18>
                    </ji>
                <CI>
                    <action>INSERT</action>
                    <pg>M9</pg>
                    <pr>
                        <action>INSERT</action>
                        <pc>GL1003</pc>
                        <pc_type>AMOUNT</pc_type>
                        </pr>
                </CI>
                
        </ps>
    </Emp>
</query>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried, what errors faced etc.

Comment: Thanks @Prophet , updated in the question.

Comment: Do you have example input XML, and the output you'd expect?

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates I have updated in the question.

Comment: So you want to remove all the `<action>` nodes?

Comment: @tim_yates - if I use my current code then all <action? nodes are getting removed but I want to only have only those fields which I will maintain in some parameters with x-path. Example if I put ji/action in parameter then only ji/action should be the output all other solution is all fields value should be set as "X" other than ji/action.

Comment: can't we read the node name using x-path?